# TensorFlow - FailedPreconditionError using tf.train.match_filenames_once()

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read some .wav files using `tensorflow`, using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once('audio_dataset/*.wav')
count_num_files = tf.size(filenames)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, file_contents = reader.read(filename_queue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(num_files):
        audio_file = sess.run(filename)
        print(audio_file)
```

I'm running `tensorflow` in a `Python 3.5` environment, using `Jupyter notebook`.

in order to read audio files, I need to use a dependency, the `Bregman Toolkit`, which uses `Python 2.X`.

documentation [Bregman Toolkit](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3) says that you can set up a `python 2.X` kernel alongside `python 3X`, doing:

```
$ python2 -m pip install ipykernel

$ python2 -m -ipykernel install --user
```

which I did. Jupyter has now the option of starting either `2.X` or `3.X` kernels.

but after all setup, when I try to run the code, I get this long Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames_7
     [[Node: matching_filenames_7/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames_7"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames_7)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a6f1ad8baaa4> in <module>()
      9 with tf.Session() as sess:
     10     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
---> 11     num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)
     12 
     13     coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames_7
     [[Node: matching_filenames_7/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames_7"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames_7)]]

Caused by op 'matching_filenames_7/read', defined at:
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-a6f1ad8baaa4>", line 3, in <module>
    filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once('audio_dataset/*.wav')
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 68, in match_filenames_once
    collections=[ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/Users/meme/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames_7
     [[Node: matching_filenames_7/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames_7"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames_7)]]
```

can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate fix is to add the following line:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

...before this line:

```
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
```

However, I'd like to show you a new and slightly easier way to write your program using the `tf.contrib.data` API (available in TensorFlow 1.3, and will become `tf.data` in TensorFlow 1.4):

```
import tensorflow as tf

filenames = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.list_files('audio_dataset/*.wav')
name_and_content = filenames.map(lambda x: (x, tf.read_file(x))
iterator = name_and_content.make_one_shot_iterator()
filename, file_contents = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  try:
    while True:
      audio_file = sess.run(filename)
      print(audio_file)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:  # Raised when there are no more files.
    pass
```